# Check if parent element contains certain child element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div id="example">
  <div id="test"></div>
</div>

<div id="another">Blah</div>
```

I want to set `$('#another').hide()` but only if `#example` contains a child element called`#test`, is this possible? It seems like it would be.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Use `length`

```
if ($('#example').find('#test').length) {
    // found!
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I think what you are looking for is the following

```
if (jQuery.contains($('#example'), $('#test')) {
    $('#another').hide();
}
```

This might work as well, not sure off the top of my head.

```
if ($('#test', $('#example')).size() > 0) {
    $('#another').hide();
}
```

Comment: `size()`. Haven't seen that in a long time! `length` ftw.

Comment: Should 'contains' be called with a DOM element as parameter and not a jQuery object? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/

Comment: Should this answer be updated to make use of "has()" as in:
`$('#test').has('#example') {
      $('#another').hide();
}`

Answer (score 6):

jQuery manual suggests to use:

```
if ($('#parent').has('#child').length) {
    //do something
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/has/

Answer (score 4):

```
<script>
    var test = $('#example #test').length();
    if(test !== 0){
        $('#another').hide();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `test` will never be `undefined`

Comment: length is not a function --> `length`. And it's also falsy so you can get rid of `!==0` and just do `if (test)`

Answer (score 2):

it's pretty simple.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('#example').children('#test').length > 0)
    {
        $('#another').hide();
    }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8rrTp/