# Apply change to all parent elements that contains a certain child element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to do the same thing as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833853/check-if-parent-element-contains-certain-child-element-using-jquery) but my parent element does not have an id. It does have a class through. Basically I have multiple elements of the same class and some have a child element. If a member of the class `example` contains the child, apply some CSS change. Is this possible and how would I do it?

For example:

```
<div class="example">
    <div id="findMe"></Div>
</div>
<div class="example">
  <!-- This div would not be found -->
</div>
```

My guess was:

```
let parents = $(".example");
for (var i=0; i < parents.length; i++) {
    if (parents[i].find('#test').length) {
        parents[i].css("prop", "value")
    }
}
```

but `parents[i].find is not a function`

Comment: Are you sure that your parents variable is an array? I think jquery just returns the first ".example" and not all of the examples.

Comment: So you only want to select `div.example` elements that contains `#findMe`? Since ID must be unique in the document, you just need to do `$('#findMe').closest('.example')`, since you will only ever have a single parent that matches this criteria.

Comment: `parents[i]` is an `HTMLElement`, not a jQuery object.

Comment: You might want to look at [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and/or [`has`](https://api.jquery.com/has/#has-selector).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you shouldn't have multiple instances of the same ID in a document. But in your example, you were pretty close. However, if you're already using jQuery it will make your life a bit easier.

```
<div class="example">
    <div class="findMe"></Div>
</div>
<div class="example">
  <!-- This div would not be found -->
</div>
```

jQuery:

*(I'm using the $ to denote a jQuery collection you wouldn't need it)*

A jQuery collection (in this case created by find) always has a length. So you need to test if it's empty. Also $.each() is basically looping through the collection.

```js
let $parents = $('.example');
$parents.each(
    function(){
      var $el = $(this);
      if($el.find('.findMe').length !=0){
         $el.css('background', 'red');
      }
    }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:100px;" class="example">
    <div class="findMe">Hello, World!</Div>
</div>
<div style="height:100px;border: solid 1px #000" class="example">
  <!-- This div would not be found -->

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As `Heretic Monkey` said in the comments above, you can use [has](https://api.jquery.com/has/#has-selector) from jQuery to do this easily.

```js
$(".example").has(".findMe").css("background-color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:100px;" class="example">
    <div class="findMe">Hello, World!</Div>
</div>
<div style="height:100px;border: solid 1px #000" class="example">
  <!-- This div would not be found -->
</div>
```